# DELETE EXCEPT TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is there any way to delete all the rows in a table except one (random) row, without specifying any column names in the `DELETE` statement?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]([Id] INT)
INSERT [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1] SELECT 1
INSERT [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1] SELECT 2
INSERT [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1] SELECT 3

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]

DELETE
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
```

The final `SELECT` should yield one row (could be any of the three).

Comment: Are you trying to SELECT one random row, or trying to remove all but one random row from the table?

Comment: Does the table have a PK?  If so a simple where PK != (select max(PK))

Comment: Why do you need it without specifying a column name?

Comment: @Magnus - I don't really, I just wondered if it was possible to combine `DELETE` and `EXCEPT`..

Comment: @TomHunter ok, so you know how to do it _if_ you specify a column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT newid())) AS RN
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

Or similar to @abatishchev's answer but with more variety in the ordering and avoiding deprecated constructs.

```
DECLARE @C INT
SELECT @C = COUNT(*) - 1 
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]

IF @c > 0
BEGIN
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP(@C) *
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
ORDER BY NEWID()
)
DELETE FROM CTE;
END
```

Or a final way that uses `EXCEPT` and assumes no duplicate rows and that all columns are of datatypes compatible with the `EXCEPT` operator

```
/*Materialise TOP 1 to ensure only evaluated once*/
SELECT TOP(1) * 
INTO #T
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
ORDER BY NEWID()

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1] T1
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM #T
             EXCEPT
             SELECT T1.*)
)
DELETE FROM CTE;

DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: So you still have to specify a column name, only that you create it yourself in the CTE

Comment: abatishchev's answer can do it without that. It currently references a column name but shouldn't need to.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm getting some really weird behavior with your last one.. I'm running just the SQL in the CTE and seem to get random rows back each time I run it!  Sometimes 2 rows, sometimes 3, sometimes 1 and even zero rows..!  Doesn't always leave only 1 row if you add the DELETE bit either.  (Running this on 2008R2 now.)

Comment: @TomHunter Ah did occur to me that might be a bit dodgy. It is probably reevaluating the `top 1 order by newid` expression for each row in `T1`. The plan I get with your 3 row table in the question on 2008 has a spool. The `TOP 1` is only evaluated once and then the result is replayed. To guarantee it is only evaluated once you would need to use a `#temp` table (`SELECT TOP(1) * INTO #T FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1] ORDER BY NEWID()`) and reference that in the CTE instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
declare @c int
select @c = count(*) - 1 from [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]

IF @c > 0
BEGIN

set RowCount  @c

delete from [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
END
```

Comment: "Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT together with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this answer to overcome the column name objection above and fix a few other issues.

Comment: With @MartinSmith edit this is a good answer. A minor nitpick, though, is that is now deletes the "bottom" random row rather than the `TOP` random row.

Comment: @MatthewPK - That is very a philosophical nit pick. If they are sorted randomly the two cases are surely indistinguishable to all intents and purposes? (Edit: Although in fact there is no random sorting here anyway. It is undefined order rather than random order)

Comment: @MartinSmith you are completely correct. For sure the "randomness" of the `TOP` is equivalent to the "randomness" of the "bottom". The reason it *may* be relevant is of the OP intends to `SELECT` the same "random" row multiple times using the same `TOP` logic.

Comment: @TomHunter: Right, considering that point, I guess it will affect SELECT not DELETE, will it not?

Answer (score 2):

No. 
You need to use a column name (such as that of the primary key) to identify which rows you want to remove.

"random row" has no meaning in SQL except its data. If you want to delete everything *except* some row, you must differentiate that row from the others you with to `DELETE`

`EXCEPT` works by comparing the `DISTINCT` values in the row.

**EDIT:** *If* you can specify the primary key then this is a trivial matter. You can simply `DELETE` where the PK `<>` your "random" selection *or* `NOT IN` your "random" selection(s).

**EDIT:** Apparently I'm wrong about the need to specify *any* column name, you can do it using the assigned `ROW_NUMBER`.. But I'm not going to delete my answer because it references your use of `EXCEPT` which was discussed in the comments. You **cannot** do it without *deriving* some column name like that from `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (SQL 2008)

```
DECLARE @Original TABLE ([Id] INT)
INSERT INTO @Original(ID) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @Original(ID) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @Original(ID) VALUES(3)

SELECT * FROM @Original;

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ROW, ID FROM @Original)
DELETE @Original
FROM @Original O
INNER JOIN CTE ON O.ID = CTE.ROW
WHERE ROW > 1

SELECT * FROM @Original
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the simplest answer may be the best. The following should work:

```
Declare @count int
Set @count=(Select count(*) from DeleteExceptTop1)-1
Delete top (@count) from DeleteExceptTop1
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been answered but what about?

```
DELETE 
FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1]
Where Id not in (
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1])
```

Comment: Yup, don't need to if you are deleting the whole row. (on SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Last line should be like the following:
SELECT TOP 1 (Id) FROM [dbo].[DeleteExceptTop1])